# hiding previous array items when on array item, php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

i have this array

```
array [ 

    U => [],
    V => [],
    W => [],
    X => [],
    Y => [],
    Z => []

];
```

The array depicts a list of items that are shown on the page.
I only want to show array items that follow the current item,

for example, if i was on item V , i only want to see

```
    W => [],
    X => [],
    Y => [],
       Z => []
```

Comment: Get the index of the current item, then use `array_slice()` to extract the elements after that.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to increment a letter key. For example:

```
$current = 'V';

for ($letter = ++$current; $letter != 'AA'; $letter++) {
    // show the item at $array[$letter];
}
```